# How to push to array value of reducer state in redux toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a simple reducer function

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { TSnackBarProps } from 'plugins/notification/NotificationContext';
import { MAX_STACK } from 'plugins/notification/NotificationsStack';

interface INotificationState {
  notifications: TSnackBarProps[];
}

const initialState: INotificationState = {
  notifications: [],
};

const notificationSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'notification',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addNewNotification(state, action: PayloadAction<TSnackBarProps>) {
      const { notifications } = state;
      const { payload: notification } = action;
      if (notifications.find((n) => n.severity === notification.severity && n.key === notification.key)) {
        return;
      }
      if (notifications.length >= MAX_STACK) {
        notifications.splice(0, notifications.length - MAX_STACK);
      }

      state.notifications.push(notification);
    },
  },
});
export default notificationSlice.reducer;
```

But, it throws the error as shown below:
[image]

I am just starting to write this reducer and got stuck here. Thanks for your help.

Also, TSnackBarProps is just SnackBarProps type from material-ui with severity property added.

Comment: u should provide more details , like interfaces and actions and some more . and i think your reducer looks weird!

Comment: How its related to redux toolkit? You assign `readonly string[]` instead of `string[]`

Comment: @b3hr4d Full code added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`immer`'s `Draft` type, which is used by RTK removes the `readonly` temporarily from all state types so that you can freely modify it. Unfortunately, that goes a little bit too far in this case.

But of course: you know better than TypeScript here. So you could just cast your state variable, which is `Draft<INotificationState>` at the moment to `INotificationState` to assign to it, which is a perfectly valid thing to do in a situation like this.